# What is a bolt connector?

Tags: connector, network-protocols, neo4j

In the article [Configure connectors - Operations Manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/connectors/) of Neo4j, there is a term "bolt connector":

[image]

But searching the web with the query [`bold connector`](https://www.google.com/search?q=bold+connector&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=AOaemvJ330Goo_HDYQ6cJljerQSt0u8Nmg%3A1632828576723&ei=oPxSYcDWK7aA1e8Py7KA0Ak&oq=bold+connector&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyCAgAEAUQChAeMggIABAIEAoQHjIGCAAQCBAeOgcIABBHELADOgQIABBDOgYIABAHEB5KBAhBGABQ7bIJWPS5CWDiugloAXACeACAAboBiAGXBpIBAzEuNZgBAKABAcgBCMABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjApq26yKHzAhU2QPUHHUsZAJoQ4dUDCA0&uact=5) or [`bold protocol`](https://www.google.com/search?q=bold+protocol&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=AOaemvKikJ7wjZUzsdOcmRZ79lbJ1zsmWg%3A1632828732733&ei=PP1SYcWhLM6A-AayvqmgBA&oq=bold+protoca&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMYADIGCAAQDRAeMggIABAIEA0QHjoLCAAQsAMQBxAKEB46CwgAELADEAgQChAeOgkIABCwAxAIEB46BAgjECc6BQgAEJECOgQIABBDOgQILhBDOgUIABDLAToLCAAQgAQQsQMQgwE6BQgAEIAEOggIABAWEAoQHjoGCAAQFhAeSgQIQRgBULStCFjkwghgjskIaAJwAHgAgAG_AogB3Q6SAQcwLjUuMy4xmAEAoAEByAEDwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz) I don't see anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bolt protocol (https://7687.org/) is an application protocol developed by Neo4j, which runs over TCP or WebSocket.

This is used by application developers together with [Neo4j drivers](https://neo4j.com/developer/language-guides/) to connect to, execute transactions and retrieve results from Neo4j servers.

Comment: do you know why they have to make their own protocol instead of using popular ones, like HTTP? Those pages don't seem to explain that.

Comment: Historically, Neo4j as a server started with HTTP and these APIs are still around today.
The Bolt protocol is more compact, and the driver API that builds upon it provides a more consistent developer experience across programming languages. You can watch this to understand the rationale behind Bolt: https://neo4j.com/videos/neo4j-online-meetup-16-an-introduction-to-neo4j-bolt-drivers/